# Confused about why having equal coefficents satisfy closure rules of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book says to verify the below quadratic polynomial is a subspace we take the linear combination of 2 members

$$M = \{a +ax+ax^2 \mid a\ \in \Bbb{R}\} = \{(1 +x+x^2) \cdot a \mid a \in
\mathbb R\}$$

Sample linear combination as follows:
$$r \cdot (a +ax +ax^2)+s \cdot(b+bx+bx^2)=(ra+sb)+(ra+sb)x+(ra+sb)x^2$$

I am confused on why having common coefficients in the sample linear combination satisfies closure for the subspace?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $M$. It read to me: "$M$ is a polynomial such that $a$ there exists $R$ equal to another polynomial times $a$ such that  $a$ there exists $\mathbb{R}$". This sentence doesn't make any sense.  I'm guessing that $M$ is the space of all polynomials of the form $a + a x + ax^2$ for some $a$, in which case the right-hand side of your expression is of this form, and so it's in the subspace.  But I'm not sure, because the definition of $M$ that you've written doesn't make sense.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @march It seems the question just needed an edit. The OP used curly braces `{` and `}` for the sets (as one would naturally try, when trying MathJax for the first time), so I replaced them with `\{` and `\}`. The `\exists`, I'm pretty sure, was supposed to be an `\in`. The question seems more sensible now.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks, I should have guessed that that was the case!

Comment: @InnerSpeaker You're very, very close to the answer. Can you write $(ra + sb) + (ra + sb)x + (ra + sb)x^2$ in the form $c(1 + x + + x^2)$? What would $c$ be in this case?

Comment: Hint. Think more generally: show that for any element $v$ in any vector space the set of scalar multiples of $v$ is a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, still getting the hang of MathJax. So c would be just another scalar. I'm trying to type out the equation, but not sure how to format in the comment section.

Comment: ok so... $(ra+sb+cw)+(ra+sb+cw)x+(ra+sb+cw)x^2$. w is just another scalar I picked. So in this case I checked a linear combination with 3 members.

Comment: @InnerSpeaker No problem! By the way, if you want to draw my attention to a comment (i.e. send me a notification), you need to tag me (like I did to you, though as the OP, I think it's unnecessary?). I wouldn't say $c$ is "just another scalar". I was trying to point you towards what ConMan explains in his answer. The $c$ is less an unknown quantity (like $a, b, r, s$), but a placeholder for a number for you to fill in. Essentially, I wanted you to see that $c$ would just be $ra + sb$ in this case; you can factor $(ra + sb)$ out from the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire definition of $M$ is that it contains polynomials of the form $\square + \square x + \square x^2$, where the values in $\square$ are the same.

In your example linear combination, we could set $ra + sb = c$, and noting that $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a given, then clearly $r(a + ax + ax^2) + s(b + bx + bx^2) = (ra + sb) + (ra + sb)x + (ra + sb)x^2 = c + cx + cx^2 \in M$.